# Angular custom directive - pass reference to parent function

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm refactoring some code into a custom directive which takes a list of users from the parent scope and presents them in tabular format. The application user can select one of the users in the table to view details. The `users` and the `setUser()` function are in the parent controller, not the directive controller; so I pass the users to the directive, and create a reference to the `setUser()` function.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'app/view.html',
        controller : 'ViewController',
        scope: {
            setUser: '&',
            users: '='
        }
   }
});
```

This is the relevant code for `view.html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-click="setUser(user)">...</div>
</div>
```

This is how I use the directive:

```
<my-directive users="users" set-user='setUser()'></my-directive>
```

The problem is that when I click the user in the table, and the setUser function is called, the user passed to the function is always undefined. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I make some changes, you can try it:

```js
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'app/view.html',
        controller : 'ViewController',
        scope: {
            setUser: '=', //Changed '&' -> '='
            users: '='
        }
   }
});
```

and

```html
<my-directive users="users" set-user="setUser"></my-directive> //Change setUser() -> setUser
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a different function in your directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-click="doSetUser(user)">...</div>
</div>
```

And in the directive link/controller:

```
$scope.doSetUser = function(user) {
  // Call the function bound to the directive with extended scope
  $scope.setUser( {user: user} );
}
```

This way, the function you pass to the directive will have access to the `user` variable right in the HTML (technically, its scope is extended with the local `user` variable), hence you can do:

```
<my-directive users="users" set-user='setUser(user)'></my-directive>
```